# Showing $\log(f(z))-\log(z^n)$ is single-valued holomorphic.

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers

For context, I am currently working through "Dynamics in One Complex Variable" by John Milnor, specifically, Lemma A.2 in Appendix A. The problem I'm facing is as follows:

Let $f:\mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function that contains no zeros in the annulus region $\{z : r_0 < \vert z \vert < r_1 \}$. Let $n$ denote the number of zeros in the disk $\mathbb{D}_r$ where $r<1$.
I want to show that if $r_0 < r < r_1$, then we have that $\log(f(z)) - \log(z^n)$ is single valued and holomorphic on this annulus. I believe the idea would be to Taylor expand $f(z)$ and combine the logarithms somehow so that the imaginary part cancels out somehow.. but I can't seem to get it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One needs to show that $F(z) = f(z)/z^n$ satisfies
$$ \tag{$*$}
 \oint_\gamma \frac{F'(z)}{F(z)} \, dz = 0
$$
for every closed curve $\gamma$ in the annulus $A = \{z : r_0 < \vert z \vert < r_1 \}$.

Here one can use the [argument principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle):
$$  \tag{$**$}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma \frac{F'(z)}{F(z)} \, dz = 
\sum_{k=1}^n N(\gamma, a_k) - n \cdot N(\gamma, 0)
$$
where $N(\gamma, a)$ is the winding number of $\gamma$ with respect to $a$, and $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ are the zeros of $f$ in $\Bbb D_r$, counted with multiplicity. All $a_k$ lie in the disk $\Bbb D_{r_0}$ and therefore in the same component of $\Bbb C \setminus \gamma$ as the origin. It follows that $N(\gamma, a_k) = N(\gamma, 0)$ for all $k$, so that the right-hand side of $(**)$ is zero, and that proves $(*)$.

Then
$$
 g(z) = \int_{z_0}^z \frac{F'(w)}{F(w)} \, dw
$$
is well-defined in $A$, here $z_0 \in A$ is a fixed point and the integral is taken along *any* path from $z_0$ to $z$ in $A$. $g$ satisfies
$$
 \left( F(z) e^{-g(z)} \right) ' = \left( F'(z)-\frac{F'(z)}{F(z)} F(z)\right)e^{-g(z)} = 0 \, ,
$$
so that $e^{g(z)} = C F(z)$ with a constant $C$. It only remains to add a suitable constant to $g$ to obtain a holomorphic logarithm of $F$.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is a really useful explanation. I have a couple of little questions though: once we show that the closed contour integral is zero, why does that imply that g(z) is well-defined, is it because we can close the contour of g which will give us zero? Also, is g holomorphic because F'/F is ? Finally, do we know g is single valued since it is well-defined?

Comment: @OllyT777: $g$ is well-defined if $\int_{\gamma_1} \frac{F'(w)}{F(w)} \, dw = \int_{\gamma_2} \frac{F'(w)}{F(w)} \, dw$ for any two paths $\gamma_1$, $\gamma_2$ from $z_0$ to $z$ in $A$, and that is equivalent to $\int_{\gamma} \frac{F'(w)}{F(w)} \, dw = 0$ for any *closed* path $\gamma $ in $A$. And yes, “well-defined” is equivalent to “single valued” here. – $g$ is holomorphic because it is complex differentiable: $g'(z) = F'(z)/F(z)$.